# Laravel TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and I'm getting an error when click submit on my form.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>This is a test page </h3>
    <form method="POST" action="./apartment/sayLove2">
        <input name="id" value="1" type="text"/>
        <input name="team" value="roma" type="text"/>
        <input name="bestPlayerInTheWorld" value="TOTTI" type="text"/>
        <input  value="Send" type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Route**

```php
Route::post('/apartment/sayLove2', 'ApartmentController@sayLove2');
```

**Controller**

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApartmentController extends Controller
{
    public function sayLove2(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        echo $id;
        exit;
        $team = $request->input('team');
        $bestPlayerInTheWorld = $request->input('bsetPlayerInTheWorld');

        return view('sayLove', ['id' => $id, $team => $team]);
    }
}
```

**Error**

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:
>       in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
>       at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>       at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
>       at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>       at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
>   line 136
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
>       at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>       at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
>       at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>       at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
>   line 136
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
>       at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>       at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
>       at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
>       at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
>       at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
>       at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
>       at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
>       at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
>       at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php
>   line 136
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
>       at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(object(Request))
>       at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
>       at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
>       at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
>       at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
>       at require_once('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ULTest/public/index.php') in server.php line 21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at here: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection

You need to add CSRF-TOKEN.

You can add a hidden input with your form like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you define an HTML form in your application, you should include a hidden CSRF token field in the form so that the CSRF protection middleware can validate the request.

You may use the @csrf Blade directive to generate the token field:

```
<form method="POST" action="/someurl">
    @csrf
    ...
</form>
```

You can learn more about it on laravel documentation site:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-introduction

Answer (score 0):

try this if all configurations correct.
i have also faced this problem and followed too many suggestions but finally, below are worked well to me.

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score -1):

Shortest answer:

`{!! csrf_field() !!}`

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-csrf-field).